# Android exibir uma tela só na primeira vez que abrir o aplicativo

Tags: android

Existe uma maneira de rodar uma tela de especifica (como por exemplo de identificação) na primeira vez que o aplicativo for aberto? E toda vez que eu lançar uma atualização no google play, as pessoas que já possuem o aplicativo instalado e abrirem novamente após a atualização, a tela de identificação será apresentada novamente? existe uma forma de diferenciar aqueles que fazem o download para aqueles que recebem uma atualização?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use as *SharedPreferences* para guardar a versão da app.

Na actividade principal, no método `oncreate()`, obtenha essa informação e actue em conformidade.

```
String appVer = "versão actual da sua app";
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String appVer = preferences.getString("lastAppVer","");

if(lastAppVer == ""){
    // A aplicação foi instalada pela primeira vez
    // Exibir tela
}
else if(lastAppVer != appVer){
    // A aplicação foi actualizada
    // Exibir tela
}
```

Na actividade da tela a ser exibida apenas uma vez guarde a versão da sua app nas *SharedPreferences*

```
String appVer = "versão actual da sua app";
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
preferences.edit.putString("lastAppVer",appVer).apply();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ramaral!

Comment: o context meu fica em vermelho, pq?

Comment: @EvandroAguiar `context` é um objecto do tipo *Context*. Se estiver a usar o código numa *Activity* substitua por `this`.