# Notificação as 0h00 sem precisar iniciar aplicação

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notification

Gostaria de notificar o usuário que ele tem uma despesa que vence no dia seguinte, mas sem a necessidade da aplicação estar rodando, atualmente eu tenho um código que notifica a partir do momento que eu entro na aplicação, gostaria de fazê-lo (sem interação do usuário) notificar as 0h00 todo dia no caso de ter alguma despesa vencendo no próximo dia.

Código que já tenho

LoginActivity - método onCreate

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Receiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

Serviço

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private NotificationManager mManager;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DespesaDAO DAO = new DespesaDAO(getApplicationContext());
        List<Despesa> list = DAO.getAllVencidasAmanha(calendar);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Existem "+list.size()+" despesas que vencerão amanhã!", System.currentTimeMillis());
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(list.size()) + " despesas vencem amanhã", "Fique alerta para não se endividar!", pendingNotificationIntent);
            mManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sem a aplicação estar rodando? Talvez através de uma notificação push, mas aí você vai depender de Internet.

Comment: Notificar ele como? email?celular? popup?

Comment: Notificação @Intruso, aquelas que ficam na statusbar

Answer (score 6):

A solução passa por definir no arranque do dispositivo o alarme que lançará o serviço que gera a notificação.

Esse serviço deverá ser executado todos os dias às 0 horas.

Para tal registe, no *AndroidManifest.xml*, um BroadcastReceiver que responda à *action* `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`:

```
<receiver android:name="aSuaPackage.StartUpBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Adicione esta permissão:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Nesse *BroadcastReceiver* defina o alarme:

```
public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            // Cria um Calendar para as 0 horas do dia seguinte
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

            //PendingIntent para lançar o serviço
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);

            //Alarme que se repete todos os dias às 0 horas
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                pendingIntent);

        }
    }
}
```

O serviço deverá verificar se há algum pagamento a efectuar e, se sim, lançar a notificação.

**Notas**

- É necessário executar a aplicação uma vez antes de ela poder responder à `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` *action*. O mesmo se aplica caso a sua execução tenha sido parada usando *Force Close*.
- A aplicação necessita de ser instalada na memória do celular.
- O uso do *StartUpBootReceiver* é necessário para garantir que o alarme é reposto quando o dispositivo é desligado e depois ligado.
- `setInexactRepeating()` não garante que o alarme seja disparado exactamente na hora indicada. Como isso não é relevante neste caso, o seu uso aconselha-se por ser mais eficiente a nível de recursos. Caso fosse usar-se-ia `setRepeating()`
- Na **primeira vez** que a aplicação for executada deve definir o alarme, se não o fizer ele só será definido quando ocorrer o desligar e ligar do dispositivo.

Ver esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189288/2541) para uma implementação mais completa.

Comment: Qual seria o melhor jeito de fazer o teste? Pois a notificação só irá tocar quando tiver uma despesa a vencer no dia seguinte, ou seja, a aplicação já irá ter corrido sua primeira vez, ou estou errado? @ramaral

Comment: Faça o serviço apresentar um Toast que indique que foi executado, defina o alarme para daqui a 5 minutos, desligue e ligue o dispositivo se o Toast for apresentado é porque funciona. Se você fez tudo direitinho, garanto que funciona.

Comment: eu tenho uma dúvida, caso eu instale agora o app no meu celular, eu vou precisar reiniciar o dispositivo pra que as notificações funcionem? O teste dos 5 minutos deu certo.

Comment: Sim se não fizer como eu disse na última nota.

Comment: Como eu defino esse alarme na primeira vez q executo o app? @ramaral

Comment: Adapte o código desta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63467/2541). A resposta mostra como executar código só na primeira vez que abrir o aplicativo. O código a executar é igual ao que está no *BroadcastReceiver*

Comment: Conseguiu implementar? Tem mais alguma dúvida?

Comment: Implementei, mas ele não toca 0h00, toca alguns minutos depois do app se iniciar @ramaral

Comment: Esse é o comportamento normal do AlarmManager quando a data/hora definida está no passado. Na definição do Calendar acrescente `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` a seguir à linha `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: Qual a finalidade dessa linha? @ramaral

Comment: `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` define o Calendar para a hora e dia actual, como se pretende que o alarme seja activado no dia seguinte adiciona-se um dia com `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`

Comment: Você usa `new Intent(context, MyService.class);` então além do BroadcastReceive, é necessário criar uma classe para o serviço? Como seria definir exatamente esse horário: 19:30:12hr para notificações diárias?

Comment: Em qual método eu lançaria minha notificação?!

Comment: O BroadcastReceiver serve para definir o AlarmManager que lançará um serviço no horário estabelecido. O serviço, do tipo IntentService, lançará a notificação no método `onHandleIntent()`