# Notificações diárias em um horário específico definido pelo usuário

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Criei um método para enviar uma notificação para o usuário com o nome `sendNotification()` usando  [`NotificationCompat.Builder` e `NotificationManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

Preciso que essa notificação seja lançada todos os dias às **07:30AM**, podendo esse horário ser ajustado pelo usuário, persistindo esse horário usando a classe `SharedPreference`.

Me parece que com a classe pública [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) é possível realizar esse procedimento, mas não tenho certeza se tenho que criar um serviço ou se ele mesmo seria o próprio serviço.

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105275/35406), bastaria definir a hora exata, como por exemplo às **07:30AM**. Então na minha aplicação eu inseri desta forma:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Porém fiz vários testes, e não está notificando corretamente com o horário especificado.

Para não poluir muito aqui de código, coloquei o que fiz [**no GitHubGist**](https://gist.github.com/cleidimarviana/70322528a9f60e57d1e70685e561b11c).

Como poderia ser feito essa notificação diariamente com um horário específico?

Comment: Explique o que quer dizer com "não está a funcionar correctamente"

Comment: @ramaral não está lançando a notificação para o usuário.

Comment: Da forma como está, com `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`, só é lançada no dia seguinte. Leia os comentários lá na outra pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral em alguma hipótese é possível lançar tipo daqui a pouco? Como seria?

Comment: Tire essa linha.

Comment: @ramaral tirei mas não funcionou.

Comment: O código foi testado antes de responder àquela pergunta. Não esqueça as permissões. Se targetSdkVersion for 24 há alterações também no que diz respeito ao ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED. Teste com targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: @ramaral Será que essa permissão entra no conceito de permissão em tempo real? Estou no mercado, logo chegando em casa faço o teste. Você chegou a ver meu código? Viu algo de errado?

Comment: Não, apenas tem de tirar aquela linha. Tenha em atenção as notas e comentários na outra resposta.

Comment: @ramaral "Não" para qual pergunta? Cheguei em casa pesquisei, realmente o RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED não entra no conceito de Permission Runtime. Vou pesquisar mais um pouco para saber o que pode ser isso. Eu li os comentários lá, vi que funcionou para o rapaz, então deveria funcionar aqui pra mim também, considerando que não mudei nada no código além da hora e a retirada da linha, como você pode ver no githubgist. Mas enfim, agradeço pela atenção e desculpe a ignorância.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o código do `BroadcastReceiver` da [resposta que refere](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105275/35406) e implementando o que é referido nas notas, será assim:

```
public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String HOUR = "hour";
    private static String MINUTE = "minute";


    public static void setAlarm(Context context, int hour, int minute){
        SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        preferences.edit()
                .putInt(HOUR, hour)
                .putInt(MINUTE, minute)
                .apply();
        setAlarm(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            setAlarm(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private static void setAlarm(Context context) {

        int hour = getHour(context);
        int minute = getMinute(context);

        if(hour == -1 || minute == -1){
            //nenhum horário definido
            return;
        }

        // Cria um Calendar para o horário estipulado
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        //Se já passou
        if(isDateBeforeNow(calendar)){
            //adiciona um dia
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }


        //PendingIntent para lançar o serviço
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Cancela um possível alarme existente
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        //Alarme que se repete todos os dias a uma determinada hora
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
    }

    private static int getHour(Context context){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getInt(HOUR, -1);
    }
    private static int getMinute(Context context){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getInt(MINUTE, -1);
    }

    private static boolean isDateBeforeNow(Calendar calendar){
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Use o método

```
StartUpBootReceiver.setAlarm(context, hour, minute);
```

para definir/alterar o horário do alarme.

Se o dispositivo for desligado, ao ser ligado o alarme é novamente registado.

Declare o `BroadcastReceiver` no *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<receiver android:name="aSuaPackage.StartUpBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Adicione a permissão

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Implemente o serviço para lançar a notificação:

```
public class BootService extends IntentService {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public BootService() {
        super("name");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "BootService");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        //Lance a notificação aqui.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
        //Verificou-se que o iluminar do ecrã
        //não acontecia devido ao WakeLock ser
        //rapidamente libertado(apesar de PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE !?).
        try {
            //Atrasa a libertação do WakeLock
            //de forma a permitir a iluminação do ecrâ.
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            wakeLock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Declare-o no `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".BootService"/>
```

e adicione a permissão para obter o *Wake Lock*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

---

**Nota:** O primeiro lançamento de um *inexact repeating alarm*, como salientado na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), nunca será antes do tempo indicado, mas pode não ocorrer durante quase todo o intervalo, após esse tempo. Se o intervalo de repetição for grande e se definir o alarme para um horário daí a pouco tempo, o primeiro lançamento poderá só ocorrer após o intervalo decorrer.

Uma alternativa é usar o método `setRepeating()` em vez de `setInexactRepeating()`. No entanto, a partir da API 19 todos os *"repeating alarm"* são considerados *"inexact"*.

A solução passa por definir um alarme usando o método `set()` e depois adicionar ao calendário o intervalo de repetição e definir outro alarme usando `setInexactRepeating()`.

Uma possível implementação para `INTERVAL_DAY` será assim:

```
public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int REPEATING_ID = 1001;
    private static int ON_TIME_ID = 1002;
    private static String HOUR = "hour";
    private static String MINUTE = "minute";


    public static void setAlarm(Context context, int hour, int minute){
        SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        preferences.edit()
                .putInt(HOUR, hour)
                .putInt(MINUTE, minute)
                .apply();
        setAlarm(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            setAlarm(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private static void setAlarm(Context context) {

        int hour = getHour(context);
        int minute = getMinute(context);

        if(hour == -1 || minute == -1){
            //nenhum horário definido
            return;
        }
        //Cancela possiveis alarmes existentes
        cancelAlarm(context);

        Calendar calendar = getCalendar(hour, minute);

        //Se já passou
        if(isDateBeforeNow(calendar)){
            //adiciona um dia
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }else{
            //Alarme para o horário especificado
            setOneTimeAlarm(context, calendar);
            //adiciona um dia para repetir o alarme no dia seguinte
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        //Repete o alarme no dia seguinte
        setRepeatingAlarm(context, calendar);

    }

    private static void setRepeatingAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar){

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(context, REPEATING_ID);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //Alarme que se repete todos os dias a uma determinada hora
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
    }

    private static void setOneTimeAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar){

        PendingIntent pendingIntent= getPendingIntent(context, ON_TIME_ID);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //Alarme para o horário especificado
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                         calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                         pendingIntent);
    }

    private static void cancelAlarm(Context context){

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(getPendingIntent(context, ON_TIME_ID));
        alarmManager.cancel(getPendingIntent(context, REPEATING_ID));

    }

    private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, int id){
        //PendingIntent para lançar o serviço
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, id, serviceIntent, 0);
    }

    private static Calendar getCalendar(int hour, int minute){

        // Cria um Calendar para o horário especificado
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        return calendar;
    }

    private static int getHour(Context context){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getInt(HOUR, -1);
    }
    private static int getMinute(Context context){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getInt(MINUTE, -1);
    }

    private static boolean isDateBeforeNow(Calendar calendar){
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Ramaral, obrigado pela resposta! Vendo aqui o que você fez, percebi que está diferente com o que me disse para fazer antes, que era usar IntentService colocando a notificação no onHandleIntent. Enfin, não sei se tem alguma coisa a ver com fuso horário ou com o intervalo de tempo minimo. Estou colocando por exemplo uns 3 minutos após a compilação e fico aguardando e não acontece nenhuma notificação, neste caso seu, nenhum Toast é disparado.

Comment: Na minha cabeça isso funciona, porém talvez eu esteja tendo problema com o horário. Por exemplo agora é 23:13 aqui no PT-BR. então para daqui 3 minutos faço: `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);` certo?

Comment: A razão de você não estar a conseguir testar tem haver com o facto do periodo de repetição ser `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY`. Na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) diz o seguinte "Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time." O **primeiro lançamento** do alarme nunca será antes do tempo indicado, mas pode não ocorrer durante quase todo o intervalo, após esse tempo".

Comment: Para testar, substitua `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` por `30*1000`. Não sei porquê mas com IntentService não funciona.

Comment: O IntentService funciona, o problema é que eu estava a usar um Toast para ser notificado, que evidentemente não funciona num IntentService. Vou editar a resposta para usar IntentService e acrescentar um WakeLock para "acordar" o dispositivo.

Comment: Legal Ramaral, deixei para ver isso hoje, mas parece que já funciona bem. Usei o `setAlarm()` e já funcionou imediatamente, ainda não sei para daqui 24. Mas já vou validar porque já perdestes bastante tempo comigo. Qualquer coisa te aviso. Ah, tem um detalhe, o `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` está `deprecated`, e sei que provavelmente não vai dar nenhum erro, mas você sabe outro método para substitui-lo?

Comment: Sim eu sei, PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK está *deprecated*. O problema é que não há outra forma(que eu conheça) de "acordar" o dispositivo no caso do serviço servir para lançar uma notificação.