# AlarmManager e BroadcastReceiver param de funcionar quando celular é desligado

Tags: android

Criei um AlarmManager que chama um BroadCast que dispara um evento que deve acontecer de tempos em tempos. Esta funcionando porém se eu reiniciar(desligar/ligar) o celular perde o serviço e não mais o alarme é acionado.

Como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Na teoria, você tem que acordar sua aplicação neste caso. Então é usado o Wake Lock, e para isso você deve dar permissão no manifest. Exemplo: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`... Veja essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189195/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-di%C3%A1rias-em-um-hor%C3%A1rio-espec%C3%ADfico-definido-pelo-usu%C3%A1rio)

Comment: Agora na prática, não está funcionando pra mim ainda, mas mesmo assim marquei a resposta do Ramaral como válida, porém para tirar dúvida com ele depois, porque já tinha enchido o saco dele demais. Tenho que fazer outros testes ainda. Para ele funcionou lá, acredito eu.

Comment: @AckLay Diga-me o que não está a funcionar para que eu possa tentar resolver.

Comment: @AckLay Testei novamente e a notificação é apresentada, no dia seguinte, após desligar e ligar o dispositivo. Não esqueça que se ligar o dispositivo depois da hora para a qual a notificação foi agendada, ela não será apresentada.